# Christmas quine!

Tags: popularity-contest, ascii-art, quine

In the language of your choice, write a program that is arranged in the shape of a Christmas tree that prints itself in the same shape.

What is not allowed:

- Printing out the source file
- Code that is nothing but statements that get echoed by an interpreter by virtue of them being literals (eg just using a tree-shaped tower of lists in python)

Comment: "Printing out the source file" is not allowed, but is reading source **code** (not from file) and printing it allowed? If it is not, then this is practically impossible with Befunge. :/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### JavaScript

The 'star' might be a bit too large for the tree...

```
        (function _()
     {return('        (')
      +(''+''+''+''+'')
             +_+
            ')()'
           ;'We w'
          +'wis'+0+
         'h you a '
        +0+'merry Ch'
       +'ristmas, '+0+
      +'we '+0+'wish y'
     +0+'ou a merry Chr'
    +'istmas, we w'+0+'i'
   +0+'sh you '+0+'a merr'
  +'y Christmas and a h'+0+
 +'appy'+0+'new year! Ho ho'
+0+' ho! Merry '+0+'Christma'
            +'s!'
            })()
```

The zeroes are baubles and look best in the editor:

[image: Hooray for syntax highlighting!]

[image: Output in Chrome Developer tools]

Comment: Nice trick with the baubles!

Comment: I love the inclusion of "We wish you a merry Christmas!"

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby

You never said we couldn't use network access... :D

```
        #
       s="
      open(
     'http:/
    /pastebin
   .com/raw.ph
  p?i=mGzbahp5'
 ).read";s=eval(
s.gsub! /\s/,'');
      puts(
      s+'')
```

Outputs itself verbatim.

Yes, I could have used a URL shortener, but that would have made it less obvious and amusing :P Also I needed *something* to take up space; otherwise the tree would be tiny.

Execute like this:

```
ruby -ropen-uri christmasquine.rb
```

Comment: In my mind you cheated, but you're right about the rules. Outsmarted by a doorknob. Anyway, here's your upvote, for making me smile :)

Comment: @Manishearth Yep, we bend the rules a *lot* here! Part of the fun. :P (Ex. 0 character quines, etc)

Comment: @Manishearth Yeah, what Doorknob said. If you don't want a rule bent, you need to include a rule against bending that rule. Hence why the latest "reverse quine" and "mirror quine" challenges had rules against palindromes and quines shorter than 2 characters.

Comment: "You never said we couldn't use network access" No, but [loopholes that are forbidden by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) did.

Answer (score 4):

## perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$_=<<'the source';eval $_;

          #
         #*#
        print
       "#!/u".
      "sr/bin".
     "/perl \n".
    "\$_=<<'the".
   " source';eva".
  "l \$_;\n${_}th".
 "e source\n";# Mery 
#Christmas to all !!!
         ###
         ###
         #*#

the source
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a tiny one in **GolfScript**:

```
   {
  ".~  
 "2/~\
+@@2$*}.
   ~
```

Note that the code above includes two space characters at the end of the second line from the top; those spaces are essential for correct operation.  Also, the code should be saved using Unix-style (`LF`) linefeeds, not Windows-style `CR`+`LF`.

---

Here's a slightly bigger (and less whitespace-sensitive) one, including a festive message:

```
     {
    " "
   MERRY
  5*n\+\n
 CHRISTMAS
".~"+2$*1>}
     .
     ~
```

A mildly interesting feature is that the words `MERRY` and `CHRISTMAS` are not string literals, although they *are* no-ops, and are copied to the output along with the code block surrounding them.